# Excel to csv connection

Tags: excel, csv

I made a connection between excel and csv that makes a table in excel sheet with data from csv. From that data i create PivotCharts. I set the connection to restart on opening, and everything worked great, but when I closed and reopened the excel file it said it had and error and recovered the excel file it had no connection in it.

Comment: Edit your `.csv` files with `FileSystemObject` (like a `.txt` file) instead of editing them on `Excel`. This will prevent those king of errors (the same happened to me a while ago).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? I dont edit data from csv, I just use it as a table for my pivotcharts.

Comment: Ok. So retrieve the data with `FileSystemObject`.

Comment: Like in vba? Sorry but I am really confused. Can you write an example?

Comment: Yes! In `VBA`. Look, I know it's strange but I deal with `.csv` files a lot. And when I use `VBA` to deal with `.csv` files with `Excel`, everything starts to collapse!!! The files don't work properly anymore, the `.csv` files loose their properties and the `.xlsx` files get errors that can't be undone. I'm sure it's something to do with a `Microsoft` thing, but I can't pinpoint what is it! So I started to manage the `.csv` files with `FileSystemObject` and, since then, I never got any errors or bugs.

Comment: How to you make a table out of it? Like separate at commas and rows? I have all that string in one variable and it just fits it in one cell

Comment: I will prepare an example for you... Give me some time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a `c:\example.csv` file with the content:

```
0,5.324,text
4,true,other text,4.6E2
"45",,
```

As you can see, I put several kinds of values on it (`integers`, `doubles`, `strings`, `booleans`, ...).
Now, let's say you want to put the file content on an `Excel` table (starting at cell `C2`, for example).

The following code will do the trick:

```
Sub ReadCsv()
    '-----Variables:
        Dim FileName As String: FileName = "c:\example.csv"      '<-- file path
        Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject                          '<-- file system object
        Dim Reader As TextStream                                 '<-- stream
    '-----
        Dim LineTemp As String                                   '<-- temporary string
        Dim LineData() As String                                 '<-- line array
    '-----
        Dim SH As Worksheet: Set SH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("X1")  '<-- your sheet
        Dim RW As Long, CL As Long: RW = 2: CL = 3               '<-- row and column of first cell to write
    '-----Procedure:
        Set Reader = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileName)                  '<-- open file
        Do While Not Reader.AtEndOfStream                        '<-- read to the end
            LineTemp = Reader.ReadLine                           '<-- record the line
            LineData = Split(LineTemp, ",")                      '<-- split the data
            For x = LBound(LineData) To UBound(LineData)         '<-- get the data
                SH.Cells(RW, CL).FormulaR1C1 = LineData(x)       '<-- write the data
                CL = CL + 1
            Next x
            CL = 3: RW = RW + 1
        Loop
        Reader.Close                                             '<-- close file
End Sub
```

The result is the following:

[image: contents from .csv]

Don't forget to add the library `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` to your references. You can do it in `Tools` > `References`.

This is the method I use to prevent any kind of conflict between `Microsoft Excel` and `.csv` files. It always works...